# Interpolation between two distributions

Tags: distributions, median, interpolation

I have a list of empirical measurements describing the rents of apartments grouped by the apartment's size. I.e there are five categories, apartments with 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5 rooms. For each of these categories I have all four quartiles and median for the rents.

In my country the measurement of apartments is a bit weird, there are rules for a certain space in your apartment to be counted as either a full or a half room.

However it might be possible that somebody asks for the rent of a 3 room apartment. I don't have explicit data for 3 room apartments.

Is it ok to just linear interpolate the quartils between the 2.5 room and 3.5 room distribution in that case? I'm not sure what's the keyword I should be looking for to solve my problem.

A real life example, the prices are per square meter of the apartment (buying prices though, not rent prices, my fault in formulating the question). The prices vary depending on the region in my country, they stay constant within the region and only one region is of interest at a time.

```
[
  {
    "type":2.5,
    "values":[
      4400.0, // Q1 - 1.5 IQR
      6600.0, // Q1
      7600.0, // Median
      8600.0, // Q3
      10800.0 // Q3 + 1.5 IQR
    ]
  },
  {
    "type":3.5,
    "values":[
      4300.0,
      6500.0,
      7500.0,
      8400.0,
      10600.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "type":4.5,
    "values":[
      4200.0,
      6200.0,
      7200.0,
      8100.0,
      10300.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "type":5.5,
    "values":[
      4000.0,
      6000.0,
      7000.0,
      7800.0,
      9900.0
    ]
  },
  {
    "type":6.5,
    "values":[
      3900.0,
      5800.0,
      6700.0,
      7500.0,
      9600.0
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can do this simply. You might need to model the distributions first, and then interpolate the parameters, or find how the parameters vary with rooms. Maybe a bit more detail about the data might help.

Comment: @SatwikPasani I added an example output I get :)

Comment: In short, *yes.*  You are merely interpolating within a quantile regression and assuming a piecewise linear model for each of the quantiles.

Answer (score 0):

### You should:
1.describe your distributions
2. Find the "mean" of the distributions.

1. Quartiles and median are descriptive parameters of the distribution (they are describes something, but not all). Why not use an empirical probability distribution function? This way you will describe the distribution as accurately as possible.
2. Natural distance between distributions - Monge-Kantorovich, Wasserstein, or Earth Movers Distance (all the same), calculated by optimal transport. The Wasserstein barycenter is located in the center between the distributions.

**So use Python, PythonOT library, fuction ot.bregman.barycenter like in [example](https://pythonot.github.io/auto_examples/barycenters/plot_barycenter_1D.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-barycenters-plot-barycenter-1d-py)**